# need an advice to avoid multiple functions

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

I'm trying to write a function using jQuery which allows me to show or hide a DIV. Here a sample of the code, I just need help to re-write the function to avoid duplication :

```
<ul id="link">
  <li>
    <a id="myLink1" href="javascript:;">Lister</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="myLink2" href="javascript:;">Afficher</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="contenu">
<div id="myDiv1">             
  <p> Bienvenue </p> 
</div>
<div id="myDiv2">             
   <p> bob </p>
</div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       var par = $("#myDiv1");
       $(par).hide();
      $("#myLink1").click(function(e){
        $(par).toggle();
        e.preventDefault();
      });

    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
       var par = $("#myDiv2");
       $(par).hide();
      $("#myLink2").click(function(e){
        $(par).toggle();
        e.preventDefault();
      });

    });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbv4Y/)

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

1) You just need one DOM ready handler `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

2) You can use **[Attribute Starts With](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** Selector [name^="value"] to selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

3) Use **[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)** to loop through all the links where id name start with `myLink`

4) Use **[match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** with proper regex to get the id number of your link then toggle the div with that id number respectively.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id^="myDiv"]').hide();
    $('[id^="myLink"]').each(function () {
        $(this).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+$/);
            $('#myDiv' + id).toggle();
        });
    });
})
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbv4Y/2/)**

Comment: This is a nice general solution, but for this particular case, you could also just list the actual ids in the selector, like `$('#myDiv1, #myDiv1').hide();` etc. Performance-wise, it's probably faster, if the code had to run 1000s of times. ;)

Comment: I don't understand why the DIV are not hidden while I call the function

Comment: Did you check my demo?

Comment: Yes I did, If I hit "lister tout" then "afficher membre", the div which contains "liste tout" is not hidden, why ?

Comment: You just need to add `.siblings('div').hide()`. Here is the updated Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jbv4Y/3/

Answer (score 5):

Do this instead :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $($(this).attr('href')).toggle();
    });
});
```

Remember to add the `id` of the `div` in the `href` of the link.

Working jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jbv4Y/1/

Answer (score 3):

You can add few classes and href to target the element to toggle

```
<ul id="link">
    <li>
        <a id="myLink1" class="trigger" href="#myDiv1" >Lister tout</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="myLink2" class="trigger" href="#myDiv2">Afficher Membre</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="contenu">
    <div id="myDiv1" class="target">             
        <p> Bienvenue </p> 
    </div>
    <div id="myDiv2" class="target">             
        <p> bob </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //add the class target to add divs that are targeted by the links
    $(".target").hide();
    //all the links which need to trigger the toggle should have the class trigger
    $(".trigger").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //the href property of the link must have the id of the div to toggle prefixed with #
        $($(this).attr('href')).toggle()
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WFhBj/)

---

You can even simplify it using a index based solution, like below but I wouldn't recommend it

```
<ul id="link">
    <li>
        <a id="myLink1" href="#" >Lister tout</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="myLink2" href="#">Afficher Membre</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="contenu">
    <div id="myDiv1">
        <p> Bienvenue </p> 
    </div>
    <div id="myDiv2">
        <p> bob </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $targets = $("#contenu > div").hide();

    $("#link a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $targets.eq($(this).parent().index()).toggle()
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gaZV9/)

It depends on the order of `li` elements in `#link` and the contents in `#contenu` being the same.

Comment: Can you explain me how to hide other Divs when I hit on one href ?